# Grep the file in reverse order from a particular line in a file

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have this kind of logs

```
2019-11-14T20:03:48.917Z  INFO Thread1 Audit ... Operation status="success" ... id=dad69655-07d0-4daf-a639-b8e3257fa6bd msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.908Z  INFO Thread Audit Operation status="success" ... id=67ab8c3b-b57c-4328-b483-81582be0341d msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.909Z  INFO Thread Audit ... Operation status="success" ...  id=b0485887-004a-4f55-b287-f5c9cf609787 msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.911Z  INFO Thread2 Audit ... Operation status="success" ... id=35ca8c14-757f-474a-a929-494781c4679f msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.915Z  INFO Thread2 Audit ... Operation status="failure" ... id=72f73c66-da37-11e9-8d68-005056bce6a5 msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.917Z  INFO Thread1 Audit ... Operation status="success" ... id=26ece804-da3a-11e9-bfed-005056bce25b msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.919Z  INFO Thread Not ... Operation status="failure" ... id=1b31f53f-66d5-475f-ace3-ed1905e8f818 msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.921Z  INFO Thread Not ... Operation status="success" ... id=84ee4947-633f-4ccb-832e-7b380052401c msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.948Z  INFO Thread Audit ... Operation status="failure" ... id=26ece804-da3a-11e9-bfed-005056bce25b msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.950Z  INFO Thread Audit ... Operation status="success" ... id=8837cb5f-48f5-49db-8ade-a47b96527501 msg...
```

`...` means that between this there can be anything, `...` can also be a single white space sometimes.

`msg...` means that id is not always at the end of line, `msg...` can also be null sometimes.

In actual it is quite complicated but basic structure is this.

**Input** - 
My input is an id given.

and

**Condition** - condition is to look at the log line which contain this id whose OPstatus is failure and it belongs to Audit class.

After finding this log line, pick up it's thread and take all the logs belonging to that thread till previous Audit log of that thread.

So, Input are the log lines given and an id = `26ece804-da3a-11e9-bfed-005056bce25b`.

**Output** I'm expecting is this

```
2019-11-14T20:03:48.909Z  INFO Thread Audit ... Operation status="success" ...  id=b0485887-004a-4f55-b287-f5c9cf609787
2019-11-14T20:03:48.919Z  INFO Thread Not ... Operation status="failure" ... id=1b31f53f-66d5-475f-ace3-ed1905e8f818 msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.921Z  INFO Thread Not ... Operation status="success" ... id=84ee4947-633f-4ccb-832e-7b380052401c msg...
2019-11-14T20:03:48.948Z  INFO Thread Audit ... Operation status="failure" ... id=26ece804-da3a-11e9-bfed-005056bce25b msg...
```

What I tried is this -

```
awk '{if($0~/.*Audit.*26ece804-da3a-11e9-bfed-005056bce25b.*/) system("grep -w " $3 " " FILENAME "| sed \"0,/.*Audit.*Operation status="success".*/d\" | sed \"/Operation status="failure"/{n;d;}\"" )}' file.log
```

Please Help!

Comment: Do you want to find the previous Audit, even if it as a failure, too?

Comment: Also, can a thread have more than two Audit records?

Comment: What's the point of grepping for Audit when every line will match?

Comment: @Shawn: The "NotAudit" was probably originally something else.

Comment: Yes, I want to find a previous Audit if it's failure too.
Yes, a thread can have more than two Audit records
Yes, the NotAudit is something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane 'push @{ $h{ $F[2] } }, $_;
     if ("Audit" eq $F[3]) {
         print join "\n", "", @{ $h{ $F[2] } } if /status="failure"/;
         splice @{ $h{ $F[2] } }, 0, -1;
     }' -- file.log
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them back to output
- `-a` splits the input on whitespace into the `@F` array
- Every line is stored to a hash keyed by the thread name (third column, i.e.`$F[2]`)
- If the fourth column `$F[3]` is `Audit` and the line contains the failure notification, we print all the previously recorded audit lines for the same thread
- When adding a new audit line to the hash, we remove all the previous ones (see [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice))

In other words, we store all Audit lines per thread name, and print the previous ones for each failed audit.

Comment: Can't we just do something like
`grep(backwards from a particular line) Thread (till next Audit) filename.txt`

Comment: @BinglerBingler: grep only sees one line, it can't go backwards or remember context.

Comment: Edited my question a bit, so that you would understand it better

Comment: It's just printing previous audit log of that thread. I also need NotAudit logs of that thread.
Just as the output I gave.

Comment: Ouch, so I misunderstood the question. Wait a moment, then...

Comment: @BinglerBingler: Updated again.

Comment: It's also giving `2019-11-14T20:03:48.908Z  INFO Thread Audit OPstatus = success` in output

Comment: This works. Is there any way to match "failure" regex with log line because "failure" isn't printed at end of line always

Comment: Of course. If you don't know how, ask a new question, don't forget to post all relevant examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402633/to-get-a-block-of-log-lines-once-a-condition-is-met
I also had this question, can you please help?

Comment: modified question here itself

Comment: yeah for previous question, removed acceptance now.

Comment: This also prints

`2019-11-14T20:03:48.911Z  INFO Thread2 Audit ... Operation status="success" ... id=35ca8c14-757f-474a-a929-494781c4679f msg...`


`2019-11-14T20:03:48.915Z  INFO Thread2 Audit ... Operation status="failure" ... id=72f73c66-da37-11e9-8d68-005056bce6a5 msg...`

And my input also contains an id, I think that should also be needed to consider.

Comment: OK, I think I've shown you enough. If you are interested in a payed contract, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

using `awk`

```
awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " "  FILENAME)}'  filename.txt
```

Demo:

```
$cat file1.txt
2019-11-14T20:03:48.909Z  INFO Thread Audit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.911Z  INFO Thread2 Audit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.915Z  INFO Thread2 NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.917Z  INFO Thread1 NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.919Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.921Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.948Z  INFO Thread Audit Opstatus = failure
$awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " "  FILENAME)}'  file1.txt
2019-11-14T20:03:48.909Z  INFO Thread Audit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.919Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.921Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.948Z  INFO Thread Audit Opstatus = failure
$
```

Explanation:

`NF` <-- Number of fields in current row
`$NF` <--  Last field

`if($NF=="failure")` <-- Check if last field have value as failure

`system()` <--  used for calling system command

`FILENAME`  <-- In-build awk variable that contains input file name. Please note is you pass input using `<` i.e std then its value will be `-`

`grep -w " $3 " "  FILENAME`  grep for 3rd field in input file and print output

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------

## EDIT

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " " FILENAME "| sed \"0,/Audit OPstatus.*success/d\" | sed \"/failure/{n;d;}\"" )}'
```

Demo:

```
$awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " " FILENAME "| sed \"0,/Audit OPstatus.*success/d\" | sed \"/failure/{n;d;}\"" )}' file1.txt 
2019-11-14T20:03:48.909Z  INFO Thread Audit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.919Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.921Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.948Z  INFO Thread Audit Opstatus = failure
$
```

Explanation :

`sed "0,/Audit OPstatus.*success/d"` <-- Delete all rows from start till pattern

`sed "/failure/{n;d;}"` <-- Delete all rows from pattern (excluding matached row) till  end `n` is used for moving to next record

Comment: What if log line extends after failure. In my case it does.
Can't I just match with Some Regex 'OPstatus=failure' for if condition?

Comment: Yes /regular expression/ ~ $0

Comment: Actually this works, but I only wanted that Thread logs above Audit failure and not the below ones.
This `awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " "  FILENAME)}'  file1.txt` command gives all that Thread logs throughout the file

Comment: @BinglerBingler try `awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " "  FILENAME "| sed  /" $3 ".*failure/d")}'  file.txt`

Comment: It's still giving log lines which are below the failure log

Comment: Sorry I missed to escape `"` in sed. Please try `awk '{if($NF=="failure") system("grep -w " $3 " " FILENAME "| sed \"/failure/,+1d\"")}' file.txt`

Comment: Edited my question, so that you would understand better picture of what I want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402633/to-get-a-block-of-log-lines-once-a-condition-is-met
I also had this question, can you please help?

Comment: Modified question here itself

Answer (score -1):

This works for your particular example:

```sh
grep ".*Thread .*= \(success\|failure\)" filename.txt
```

... gives:

```
2019-11-14T20:03:48.909Z  INFO Thread Audit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.919Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.921Z  INFO Thread NotAudit OPstatus = success
2019-11-14T20:03:48.948Z  INFO Thread Audit Opstatus = failure
```

however, you may want to look at generalising this in a bash script going forward.
[Here's an example of the matching I used](https://regex101.com/r/7Hbs0q/1). Regex101 is a great tool for finding solutions to problems like this.

## EDIT:

To do this conditionally, simply put this into a bash script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
grep -q ".*$1 .*= failure" $2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  grep ".*$1 .*= \(success\|failure\)" $2
fi
```

and run with e.g.: `./check.sh Thread filename.txt`

Comment: OP want to search dynamically if `Opstatus = failure`.

Comment: @DigvijayS ahh you're right! I've updated my answer to address this. Thanks.

Comment: @Yasen no this checks for a failed audit log then if so it finds all other occurrences for that particular thread. I.e. it pulls out all info for a given thread if it finds an `Opstatus = failure` for that thread.